# What is wrong with my edit function in React.js ToDo app?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on internship ToDo app using React.js, and stuck on notes edit function.
The logic is mostly done, but I stuck on saving edited note with "TypeError: arr[i] is undefined".
I will post link to whole project on GitHub, the code is simple, main logic is in ToDo.js and ToDoItem.js files.
In general, I'm having problem with sending arguments from "save" function to "editItem" function. 
Help me please, I'm just newbie on React ...
https://github.com/Wonderio619/magisale-internship-todo
**ToDoItem.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './ToDoItem.css';

class ToDoItem extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            editMode: false,
        }
      };

      edit = () => {
        this.setState ({editMode: true});
      };

      save = () => {
        let updTitle = this.refs.newTitle.value;
        let updToDo = this.refs.newToDo.value;
        this.props.editItem (updTitle, updToDo, this.props.key);

        this.setState ({
          editMode: false})
      };

      renderNormal = () => {
        return (
            <div className="ToDoItem">
            <p className="ToDoItem-Text">{this.props.title}</p>
            <p className="ToDoItem-Text">{this.props.todo}</p>
            <button className="ToDoItem-Edit" onClick={this.edit}>&#x270D;</button>
            <button className="ToDoItem-Delete" onClick={this.props.deleteItem}>-</button>
        </div>
        );
      };

      renderEdit = () => {
        return (
          <div className="ToDoItem">
            <textarea ref="newTitle" defaultValue={this.props.title}></textarea>
            <textarea ref="newToDo" defaultValue={this.props.todo}></textarea>
            <button onClick={this.save} className="ToDoItem-Save">&#128190;</button>
          </div>
        );
      };

      render() {
        if (this.state.editMode) {
          return this.renderEdit ();
        } else {
          return this.renderNormal ();
        }
      }
}

export default ToDoItem;
```

**ToDo.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './ToDo.css';
import ToDoItem from './components/ToDoItem';
import Logo from './assets/logo.png';

class ToDo extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            list: [
                {
                    title: 'Cup cleaning',
                    todo: "Wash and take away the Kurzhiy's cup from WC"
                },
                {
                    title: 'Smoking rollton',
                    todo: 'Do some rollton and cigarettes'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Curious dream',
                    todo: 'Build a time machine'
                }
            ],
            title: '',
            todo: ''
        };
    };

    createNewToDoItem = () => {
      this.setState(({ list, title, todo }) => ({
        list: [
            ...list,
          {
            title,  
            todo
          }
        ],
        title: '',
        todo: ''
      }));
    };

    handleKeyPress = e => {
        if (e.target.value !== '') {
          if (e.key === 'Enter') {
            this.createNewToDoItem();
          }

        }
    };

    handleTitleInput = e => {
      this.setState({
        title: e.target.value,
      });
    };

    handleTodoInput = e => {
        this.setState({
         todo: e.target.value
      });
    };

    deleteItem = indexToDelete => {
        this.setState(({ list }) => ({
          list: list.filter((toDo, index) => index !== indexToDelete)
      }));
    };

    editItem = (updTitle, updToDo, i) => {
        let arr = this.state.list;
        arr[i].title = updTitle;
        arr[i].todo = updToDo;
        this.setState ({list: arr});
    };

    eachToDo = (item, i) => {
        return <ToDoItem
                    key={i}
                    title={item.title}
                    todo={item.todo}
                    deleteItem={this.deleteItem.bind(this, i)}
                    editItem={this.editItem.bind(this, i)}
                />
      };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="ToDo">
                <img className="Logo" src={Logo} alt="React logo"/>
                <h1 className="ToDo-Header">MAGISOFT REACT INTERNSHIP TODO</h1>
                <div className="ToDo-Container">

                    <div className="ToDo-Content">
                        {this.state.list.map(this.eachToDo)}
                    </div>

                    <div>
                       <input type="text" placeholder="Enter new title" value={this.state.title} onChange={this.handleTitleInput} onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress}/>
                       <input type="text" placeholder="Enter new todo" value={this.state.todo} onChange={this.handleTodoInput} onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress}/>
                       <button className="ToDo-Add" onClick={this.createNewToDoItem}>+</button>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ToDo;
```

Comment: Please include all your code and necessary information in your question

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant code.

Comment: Ok, it is done )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your edit item to following and it will work. Actually you are using this.editEditItem.bind(this, i). Due to which index is getting passed as the first argument.

```
editItem = (i, updTitle, updToDo) => {
    let arr = this.state.list;
    arr[i].title = updTitle;
    arr[i].todo = updToDo;
    this.setState ({list: arr});
};
```

Comment: Also if you don't want to change function definition update this line. editItem={(updTitle, updToDo) => this.editItem.bind(this, updTitle, updToDo, i)}

Comment: Shubham, than you very much, now looks like I can avoid sending this.props.key argument from "save" function, which I believe was not worked anyway. I really should learn more about bind function, it was in the code from the beginning, and I did not pay much attention on her ...